# Import module into python not found

Tags: python, import, qstk

I am trying to import the module

```
import QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil as du
```

But I get the Error

```
ImportError: No module named QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil
```

My current working directory is

```
'c:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\QSTK'
```

and in the path `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\QSTK\qstkutil` there are the files

```
qsdateutil.py
qsdateutil.pyc
qsdateutil.pyo
```

Comment: Check if "c:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages" is in the path : print sys.path . Try also to import QQSTK, QSTK.qstkutil

Comment: If your current working directory is just `'c:\\'` or something, can you do the import?

Comment: what is your pythonpath? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/2536029

Comment: I tried the print sys.path and got:

['c:\\Users\\thor\\Desktop', 'C:\\Anaconda\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Anaconda', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', u'c:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\QSTK']

Answer (score 2):

Does importing QSTK work?

```
import QSTK
```

How about QSTK.qstkutil?
If not this is most likely a sys.path problem. Please post the result of:

```
>>>import sys
>>>sys.path
```

It should look like:

```
[ [...], 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages', [...] ]
```

Another thing you can check, is if 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\QSTK\qstkutil' contains a file named '__init__.py'. From the [module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages):

> The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, __init__.py can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the __all__ variable, described later.

Comment: (srry for the poor text quality):

import QTSK or QTSK.qstkutil does not work.

Runnign sys.path gives
['c:\\Users\\thor\\Desktop', 'C:\\Anaconda\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Anaconda\\DLLs', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Anaconda', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\Anaconda\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info', u'c:\\Python27\\Lib\\site-packages\\QSTK']

Comment: The path looks fine. Do "import QSTK" and "import QSTK.qstkutil" work?

Comment: sounds like `__init__.py` is missing

Answer (score 0):

try a fresh installation and make sure you run sudo python setup.py install , command after unpack-aging , QSTK. that process links QSTK.qstkutil.qsdateutil.